# Is the gcc insane optimisation level (-O3) not insane enough?

Tags: optimization, gcc, stack-frame

As part of answering another question, I wanted to show that the insane level of optimisation of `gcc` (`-O3`) would basically strip out any variables that weren't used in main. The code was:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {
   char bing[71];
   int x = 7;
   bing[0] = 11;
   return 0;
}
```

and the `gcc -O3` output was:

```
    .file "qq.c"
    .text
    .p2align 4,,15
.globl main
    .type main, @function
main:
    pushl %ebp
    xorl %eax, %eax
    movl %esp, %ebp
    popl %ebp
    ret
    .size main, .-main
    .ident "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3"
    .section .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Now I can see it's removed the local variables but there's still quite a bit of wastage in there. It seems to me that the entire:

```
    pushl %ebp
    xorl %eax, %eax
    movl %esp, %ebp
    popl %ebp
    ret
```

section could be replaced with the simpler:

```
    xorl %eax, %eax
    ret
```

Does anyone have any idea why `gcc` does not perform this optimisation? I know that would save very little for `main` itself but, if this were done with normal functions as well, the effect of unnecessarily adjusting the stack pointer in a massive loop would be considerable.

The command used to generate the assembly was:

```
gcc -O3 -std=c99 -S qq.c
```

Comment: Can you include the full command invoking gcc?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can enable that particular optimization with the `-fomit-frame-pointer` compiler flag.  Doing so makes debugging impossible on some machines and substantially more difficult on everything else, which is why it's usually disabled.

Although your GCC documentation may say that `-fomit-frame-pointer` is enabled at various optimization levels, you'll likely find that that's not the case—you'll almost certainly have to explicitly enable it yourself.

Answer (score 6):

Turning on `-fomit-frame-pointer` ([source](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options)) should get rid of the extra stack manipulations.

GCC apparently left those in because they facilitate debugging (getting a stack trace when needed), although the docs note that `-fomit-frame-pointer` is the default starting with GCC 4.6.